# How to choose the right CPU for a web server

Tags: apache-2.2, central-processing-unit

How can i choose the right CPU for a site that runs on two servers, a web server (Apache worker MPM) and a database server (MySQL). The website is written in PHP-Mysql, with no PHP caching (as required by the owner) and it has heavy traffic (avrg concurrent users 3000~ and avrg transactions per second 7000~)

I got two options for example: 2x Octo-Core E5-2650 2.0 Ghz w/HT 32 Threads or a single Intel Xeon E3-1270V3 3.5Ghz. I have looked up the specifications of both of them and i see that the first one exceeds the second one in everything except the clock speed, What should i be looking at ?

Note: I have asked this question before a couple of days and deleted it because one of the dedicated servers providers refused to share the full CPU information, i am re-posting this after having the complete CPU specifications.

Comment: Just about any modern processor works. But in this case, use the E5-2650.

Comment: any pointers to what makes this one better ? i really want to understand what i should be looking at

Comment: It is not a duplicate because it asks about something specific.

Comment: Intel has a site for [side by side comparisons](http://ark.intel.com/compare/75056,64590) with little pop-ups explaining certain processor features as well.

Comment: It's a server CPU. It's a higher-end product line (E5 versus E3). It denotes the use of (presumably) better server equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I likely would go with the E5 - the E3v3 is a lot more modern BUT: it is a 1270 which means limited RAM and... I do not think that the advances in per core speed can outweigh the hugh number of threads you have on the E5 configuration.

That said, measure what you have in RAM - if you do 7000 TPS (Transactions per second) The database side will be an issue outside of the CPU (as in: on the IO side).

I would personally say that the CPU - outside the ridiculous wastage by using PHP to start (slow) and then not using caching (ignorant at best, sorry) you really should make sure you handle the db side properly, but that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Yeah i totally do not get why the client is refusing caching but there not much i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any modern processor works for web server purposes. But in this case, use the E5-2650 over the E3-1270.

I suggest this because it's a server CPU, supports multiple sockets and more RAM. It's a higher-end product line (E5 versus E3). It denotes the use of (presumably) better server equipment. Although, I understand that this is a hosting environment, and you'll probably end up on assembled Supermicro equipment anyway, it still makes sense to go with the mainline server-class CPU. The only exception is is you know that you're CPU-bound and have relatively low threading in your application.